# laravel, display data on a drop down from another table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Hello guys I have a table **manufacturers** (columns ***'manufacturer_id'***, ***'manufacturer'***) and want display a "select" list based by this table dynamically in a different but linked view **'asset.blade.php'**.

***Model - Asset.php***

```
namespace App;

class Asset extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'asset_id';

}
```

***Controller - AssetController***

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Asset;
use App\Manufacturer;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AssetController extends Controller
{
    public function asset(){

        $assets = Asset::all();
        return view('viewAsset', ['assets' => $assets]);
    }

    public function getmanufacturerlist() {
        $Manufacturer = Manafacturers::all();
        return view('manufacturer')->with('data', $Manufacturer);
    }

    public function add(Request $request){
        $this->validate($request, [
            'asset_id' => '',
            'asset_category_id' => 'required',
            'manufacturer_id' => 'required',
            'department_id' => 'required',
        ]);
        $assets =  new Asset;
        $assets  ->asset_id  = $request->input('asset_id');
        $assets  ->asset_category_id = $request->input('asset_category_id');
        $assets  ->manufacturer_id = $request->input('manufacturer_id');
        $assets  ->department_id = $request->input('department_id');
        $assets  ->save();
        return redirect('/viewAsset') ->with('info', 'New Asset Saved Successfully!');
    }
}
```

***manufacturer.blade.php***

```
<select name="manufacturer_id">
<option>Select a Manufacturer</option>
@foreach( $manufacturer as $manufacturers )
<option value=" <?php echo $manufacturers->manufacturer_id; ?>" > <?php echo $manufacturer->manufacturer?> </option>
 @endforeach
</select>
```

when i execute my project - it works just fine, i see the dropdown list. But if I include my `manufacturer.blade.php` in the form:

```
 @include('forms.manufacturer')
```

I get the error

```
Undefined variable: manufacturer.
```

How do i fix the error? My Laravel version is 5.4.

Comment: From docs [Including Sub-Views](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#including-sub-views) **All variables that are available to the parent view will be made available to the included view**. You need to pass `$manufacturer` from controller if you are loading sub-view `@include('forms.manufacturer')`

Comment: thanks. It worked @ljubadr

Comment: You are welcome

Answer (score 0):

You're passing `$manufacturer` as `$data` to your view.

Update it to properly pass a variable named `$manufacturer`.

```
return view('manufacturer')->with('manufacturer', $Manufacturer);
```

Or use compact for a cleaner approach:

```
return view('manufacturer', compact('manufacturer'));
```

Comment: i did try updating it to $manufacturer and i used  the compact approach  but the error still retains the same. @enriqg9

Comment: @Nii try `return view('manufacturer')->with('data', $Manufacturer);` on you controller and update this line on your view `@foreach( $data as $manufacturers )` and let me know what happens

Comment: the error msg switched to:Undefined variable: data @enriqg9